# How to combine two php codes together?

Tags: php

How can I combine the below php Code 1 into Code 2  ?

When running the URL such as :http://www.findoutbusiness.com/hkstock.php?stockno=3000

**Please visit the code: [php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWwZN.png)**

Now, I want to combine the above code 1 into the below Code 2, how can I do it ? Please help me ! I want Code 1 can run in the Code 2 as the URL.

Thank you for your help & fully support first !

Comment: Please add your code with output that you want to combine.

Comment: Why are you not write your code 1 line directly in code 2 curl link ?

Comment: I don't know how to write it, please help me.

Comment: ok, can you please put your code so i can copy and modify it.

Comment: Please see my below answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Replace the line of code on the second php. You can then remove the first php

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.findoutbusiness.com/company/" . $_GET['stockno']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this like with new line.

Old line :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.findoutbusiness.com/company/3000");
```

New Line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.findoutbusiness.com/company/" . $_GET['stockno']);
```